# Shutting down Spring application makes JNDI name for datasource go away from jdbc context

Tags: java, spring, servlets, weblogic, jndi

I'm trying to setup a web application using Spring MVC and Spring Data JPA on my Weblogic 
server. The application works fine the first time I deploy it to the Weblogic server but when I stop the application the jndi name (jdbc/myDS) to my datasource disappears from the JNDI Tree on my Weblogic server, and then when I try to start the application again I get the following error:

```
Caused By: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'jdbc.myDS'. Resolved 'jdbc'; remaining name 'myDS'
```

I'm setting up the following at startup in JPAConfiguratation.java:

```
package mySpringApp.application;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

/**
 * An application context Java configuration class. The usage of Java configuration
 * requires Spring Framework 3.0 or higher with following exceptions:
 * <ul>
 *     <li>@EnableWebMvc annotation requires Spring Framework 3.1</li>
 * </ul>
 */
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ImportResource("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class JPAConfiguration{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JPAConfiguration.class);

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL = "hibernate.format_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_NAMING_STRATEGY = "hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";

    @Resource
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws NamingException {    
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        String jndiName = "jdbc/myDS";
        DataSource dataSourceJNDINAME = (DataSource) ctx.lookup(jndiName);
        return dataSourceJNDINAME;
    ));


    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();

        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        try {
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            logger.error("Error setting datasource for entityManagerFactoryBean", e);
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        Properties jpaProterties = new Properties();
        jpaProterties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        jpaProterties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL, environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL));
        jpaProterties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_NAMING_STRATEGY, environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_NAMING_STRATEGY));
        jpaProterties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProterties);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }
```

Web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MySpringApp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>mySpringApp.application</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MySpringApp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The log output when shutting down the application the first time:

```
INFO  - onfigWebApplicationContext - Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'MySpringApp-servlet': startup date [Thu Oct 03 13:13:05 CEST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
DEBUG - DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
INFO  - DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1c51f5cb: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcesso
r,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.sprin
gframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,webConfig,JPAConfiguration,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,homeController,firstController,buildController,
greetingController,repositoryBuildService,org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryInterfaceAwareBeanPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.data.repository.core.sup
port.RepositoryInterfaceAwareBeanPostProcessor#1,org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration,requestMappingHandlerMapping,mvcContentNegotiationManager,viewControllerHandlerMapping,beanNameHandlerMapp
ing,resourceHandlerMapping,defaultServletHandlerMapping,requestMappingHandlerAdapter,mvcConversionService,mvcValidator,httpRequestHandlerAdapter,simpleControllerHandlerAdapter,handlerExceptionResolver,messageSource,viewResolver,org.spr
ingframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Http
RequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#1,buil
dRepository,org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryInterfaceAwareBeanPostProcessor#2,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration,org.springframework.transaction.config.internal
TransactionAdvisor,transactionAttributeSource,transactionInterceptor,dataSource,transactionManager,entityManagerFactoryBean,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#1,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.S
impleUrlHandlerMapping#2,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler#1,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#3,org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryInterface
AwareBeanPostProcessor#3]; root of factory hierarchy
DEBUG - DisposableBeanAdapter      - Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration'
DEBUG - DefaultListableBeanFactory - Retrieved dependent beans for bean '(inner bean)': [(inner bean), buildRepository]
DEBUG - DisposableBeanAdapter      - Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBean'
INFO  - erEntityManagerFactoryBean - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'mySpringAppPersistenceUnit'
DEBUG - SessionFactoryImpl         - HHH000031: Closing
DEBUG - tityManagerFactoryRegistry - Remove: name=mySpringAppPersistenceUnit
DEBUG - DisposableBeanAdapter      - Invoking destroy method 'shutdown' on bean with name 'dataSource'
DEBUG - DisposableBeanAdapter      - Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'JPAConfiguration'
DEBUG - DisposableBeanAdapter      - Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'webConfig'
DEBUG - DisposableBeanAdapter      - Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration'
```

I'm using:

- Spring 3.2.4.RELEASE
- Hibernate 4.2.6.Final
- Weblogic 10.3.5

Do I need to handle the shutdown of the application manually somehow? What can cause the jndi name disappear from the server context?

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can see in your log that `shutdown` is being called on the datasource when you stop your app. You need to make a call to start it up again. See here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/jdbc_admin/manage.html It's probably because your `@bean` annotation

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem.  Adding destroyMethod="" fixed it for me.

Apparently if there is no destroyMethod, Spring tries to determine what the destroy method is.  This is apparently causing the datasource to be closed and the JNDI key to be removed from the tree.  Changing it to "" forces it to not look for a destroyMethod.

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "")
public DataSource dataSource() throws NamingException{
    Context context = new InitialContext();
    return (DataSource)context.lookup("jdbc.mydatasource");
}
```

Comment: That's the answer

Comment: applying this solution works fine...but if we restart weblogic during the application is running the same behavior repeats

Comment: This answer was given 7 years ago and hopefully weblogic and/or spring have updated to resolve this issue without the workaround I proposed. I can say for certain restarting was not an issue when I implemented this solution in 2013.