# Unable to resolve datasource JNDI after web application shutdown/start in Weblogic 12c

Tags: java, weblogic, datasource

I have a DataSource configured in a Weblogic 12c as shown on the image below:

[image: Datasource]

And I also have a web application on the same Weblogic server that uses this datasource:

[image: Web Application]

Whenever I start Weblogic from the ground up everything works fine. But, after it is up, if I try to shutdown the webapplication and then start it again, I have an "javax.naming.NameNotFoundException" as shown below:

[image]

This is the code I am using to get the datasource:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
    DataSource dataSource = dsLookup.getDataSource("jdbc/xdrstoredbds");
    return dataSource;
}
```

What may I be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ends up that the cause of the problem was a Spring behavior I was unaware of. As mentioned in this other answer [Weblogic datasource disappears from JNDI tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158837/weblogic-datasource-disappears-from-jndi-tree) I had to add a destroyMethod="" to my bean definition. Without this it seems that Spring

> "tries to determine what the destroy method is. This is apparently
>   causing the datasource to be closed and the JNDI key to be removed
>   from the tree. Changing it to "" forces it to not look for a
>   destroyMethod."

My method end up looking similarly the one in the answer I mentioned:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
    return dsLookup.getDataSource("jdbc/xdrstoredbds");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your line

```
DataSource dataSource = dsLookup.getDataSource("jdbc/xdrstoredbds");
```

with

```
DataSource dataSource = dsLookup.getDataSource("java:comp/env/jdbc/xdrstoredbds");
```

Then try to run in again.
java:comp/env is the node in the JNDI tree where you can find properties for the current Java EE component

Comment: Replace your line of code segment 
DataSource dataSource = dsLookup.getDataSource("jdbc/xdrstoredbds");
with below one 
DataSource dataSource = dsLookup.getDataSource("java:comp/env/jdbc/xdrstoredbds"); 
Then try to run in again.
java:comp/env is the node in the JNDI tree where you can find properties for the current Java EE component

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. I now get this exception: weblogic.application.ModuleException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up comp/env/jdbc/xdrstoredbds in /app/webapp/xdrweb.war/490669642.; remaining name 'comp/env/jdbc/xdrstoredbds'. This error happens when I start Weblogic or when I try to start only de webapplication.