# Weblogic Database Connectionpool Unbinds , when the spring application is undeployed

Tags: spring

I'm developing a spring(4.3.2 release) application and it uses 2 connectionpool for the database operations.

The problem is that the connectionpool is unbinded from JNDI , when the application is un-deployed and it's not available for the next deployment.

This issue is happening only in the PRE-PRODUCTION environment and doesn't occur in the TEST.

Please help me with your thoughts

Thanks,
Vimal

Comment: check WebLogic's config files for differences in the the datasources section , or else check differences in your application in case that there is a custom shutdown hook clearing the resources or a flag defined during build

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have compared the datasource configurations in TEST and PRE and it looks same. There's no custom shutdown defined in the code.

Comment: @Bean
 @Qualifier("dataSource")
 public DataSource getDataSourceORAEST() throws IllegalArgumentException, NamingException {
  final JndiObjectFactoryBean factoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
  factoryBean.setJndiName("JNDI_name");
  factoryBean.setResourceRef(true);
  factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
  return (DataSource) factoryBean.getObject();
 }

Comment: Please post code inside question's body as long as it helps identifying your problem , not in comments. Anyway The above code shows that you are using a JNDI datasource configured by WebLogic. Have you checked these configurations as well in both envs?

Comment: Yes the configurations are same in both the environment.

Comment: Found a suggestion in the below link. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158334/shutting-down-spring-application-makes-jndi-name-for-datasource-go-away-from-jdb

Comment: yeap , looks like the same issue , while the application is being un-deployed, Spring is calling `close()` on the managed resource , thus invoking `close()` in the container. Did the referred [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158334/shutting-down-spring-application-makes-jndi-name-for-datasource-go-away-from-jdb#answers) worked for you ? But still does not answer why its not happening on both systems , as you said the code / configs are the same.

Comment: yep, not sure why this is not occurring in the TEST environment, Also, the same application is deployed successfully in PRE around 5 times

Comment: Hi , The above suggested change has resolved the issue. Thanks for our help